# Webpack add Lazy Loaded chunks after build

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

**Ok so here's the background info:**

I am creating a CMS and need the user to be able to add/remove plugins as they wish. The admin page is powered by Vue, so the entire admin backend is built using Webpack. I am using Vue's built-in router to allow for client-side routing and lazy-loading via Webpack code separation.

**Here's the problem:**

So the problem is that if a user adds a plugin with a backend view, say a form editor with a UI to edit the forms, that view needs to be added to the routes on the frontend to be rendered and the Vue file for the plugin's view needs to be built. That means that every time a user adds/removes a plugin, they need to build the *entire* admin site. This is stupid. Ideally, I want the user to be able to add/remove a plugin without having to build anything, but if necessary, it would be optimal if they could just build the individual plugin's Vue file into its own chunk.

But if Webpack builds just that file, is it possible to still lazy-load it? To my knowledge, Webpack keeps track of the relationships of the files it builds, so lazy-loading logic is handled by Webpack under the hood.

**TL/DR; / What a good answer will tell me:**

- Is it possible to use lazy-loading with Vue.js with the client-side router without building the router at build-time (so that the router doesn't have to be built when a plugin is added/removed)?
- Can I build a single Vue file into a chunk that can be lazy-loaded by an existing Webpack build without re-building the entire thing?
- **OR** - Is there some alternative method to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your design seems inherently flawed.  Rather than creating a component per page, the page hosting framework would instead be the component and you would dynamically load the plugins and handle each appropriately, which typically requires some sort of metadata templating structure.  If you need to lazy-load chunks, use System.import to handle the imports.  As a whole, this question feels too broad for Stack Overflow and there probably isn't a definitive correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Vue, we have done a similar implementation using React. But the  approach we followed used basic JS features only, so hopefully you should be able to do something similar. First we defined the plugin as an external dependency in the plugin loader code, so it can use the plugin methods without having it as part of the webpack package. Then every plugin is a separate webpack project which exports with this library config -

```js
output: {
   library:["registeredPlugins", "[name]"],
   libraryTarget:"umd" // or "var"
}
```

This creates `var window.registeredPlugins.somePlugin = {...}` exports in the generated script.

Next, we use the [ScriptJS](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) loader in the plugin loader code to load a plugin at run-time from its URL. We ensure every plugin has a unique name so they don't overwrite each other.

Hope this helps.